# How to plot a acf function for a time series data using `apply` in R

Tags: r

I have time-series data. I would like to apply `acf` function and plot the result for all the columns. I would like also to make the plot generate the title for each univariate series automatically.

I tried the following:

```
library(quantmod)
library(TSclust)
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)
library(vcd)
## Prepare the data
symbols = c('AZN', 'BP', 'AAPL')

## Start and end time
start = as.Date("2015-01-05")
until = as.Date("2015-12-31")

stocks.Cl = lapply(symbols, function(symbol) {
  Close = getSymbols(symbol,src='yahoo', from = start, to = until, auto.assign = FALSE)[, 4]
  names(Close) = symbol
  Close
})
stocks.Cl = do.call(merge.xts,stocks.Cl)

acf.dat <- apply(stocks.Cl, MARGIN= 2, FUN = plot(acf))
```

But I got the following:

```
Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,  : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

Comment: `apply(stocks.Cl, MARGIN= 2, FUN = function(x) plot(acf(x)))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. But how to make the title with the name for each series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an anonymous function to apply additional functions to objects passed. Instead of `apply` with `MARGIN = 2` we use `lapply` and iterate over the `names` of `stocks.Cl` to be used as title of the plot.

```
lapply(names(stocks.Cl), function(i) plot(acf(stocks.Cl[, i]), main = i))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, it generates two plots for each series. One with the series title and the other one with this title: "Series stocks.Cl[,I]"